# How to resolve error code 73 for Oracle WLS/Coherence patching?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, patch, weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

I'm trying to fix security vulnerabilities for Oracle Weblogic on Windows systems by applying the recommended patch file. However, many systems I am updating are rejecting the recommended patch - saying that coherence is not installed. The systems have been installed with fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls (which includes Coherence(?)), and I have updated OPatch to the most recent version as well. I have also set the ORACLE_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables to point to the correct file paths, and have tried running the attachHome command.

Here is what the command prompt shows after attempting to apply the patch:

Oracle Interim Patch Installer version 13.9.4.2.4
Copyright (c) 2020, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Oracle Home       : C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1
Central Inventory : C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory
from           :
OPatch version    : 13.9.4.2.4
OUI version       : 13.9.4.0.0
Log file location : C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\cfgtoollogs\opatch\opatch2020-12-29_20-42-48PM_1.log

OPatch detects the Middleware Home as "C:\Oracle\Middleware"

Verifying environment and performing prerequisite checks...
UtilSession failed: Patch 121307 requires component(s) that are not installed in OracleHome.  Or don't have required patch level. These not-installed components are oracle.coherence:12.1.3.0.0:patchlevel-(or higher),
Log file location: C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\cfgtoollogs\opatch\opatch2020-12-29_20-42-48PM_1.log

OPatch failed with error code = 73

The log file produces the same error as well.

Comment: Which patch are you trying to install ?

Comment: 30564174 and 30575273

Comment: None of these patchs are for fmw 12.2.1.4

Comment: Should I try to reinstall to fmw 12.2.1.3 and see if that works?

Comment: If your target is 12.2.1.4 you must install patch sets for 12.2.1.4.